# Forza Horizon 2 not updating?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

I'm trying to get Horizon 2 on the Xbox One to update, but whenever I log into the game, it loads normally as if it is the latest version of the game. This shouldn't be the case, as the game should tell me it's time for an update.

What I have done thus far:

1. Ran a hard connection between my Xbox and my Modem, I can logon onto live like normal, but it doesn't update.
2. Reset my modem settings, as well as flushing out the old settings on the Xbox. That didn't work.

The only other option I can think is to reset my Xbox. But I don't want to loss any data.

Is there another way to update Forza? Or is there a setting I need to enable in-game?

Comment: Just wondering, but what makes you think you don't already have the newest version?

Comment: I have seen the new cars in the more recent versions of the game online. My version doesn't have any of these cars. An example being the M4 and the M6

Comment: Both of those cars are a part of car packs, i.e DLC.

Comment: I was told that it was included in an update along with other cars like the Jeep SRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone to 'My Games & Apps' then the 'Updates' tab within that? Any applicable updates to any of your applications should be in there. If you see an update for Forza Horizon 2, click on it and select download.

The other option is to uninstall and reinstall FH2. The reinstall should be downloaded with the latest patch.

Comment: I dont see a Updates Tab in My Games and Apps